# Stable Acute Triangles in a Grid

Tags: combinatorics, ramsey-theory

The following combinatorial question came up while trying to prove a lemma for my research. Let $[N]$ denote the $N\times N$ grid inside the integer lattice $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}.$ The square corresponding to $x=(z_1,z_2)\in\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$ is $[z_1-.5,z_1+.5]\times [z_2-.5,z_2+.5]\subset\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}.$ Denote this $S(x).$

**Definition**
An *acute three-tuple* $\left\{x_1,x_2,x_3\right\}$ is a collection of three elements $x_i\in \mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z}$ so that if $y_1\in S(x_1),$ $y_2\in S(x_2),$ and $y_3\in S(x_3),$ then the triangle with vertices (y1,y2,y3) is acute.

Let $\lambda(N)$ be the size of the largest subset of $[N]$ with no acute three-tuple.

**Question**
Is $\lambda(N) = O(N^{1+\epsilon})$ for all $\epsilon>0$?

I have shown that $\lambda(N) = O(N^{1.5}),$ but the argument is not easily strengthenable.

Comment: I would dare to say that any subset of $[N\times N]$ that is not equal to its convex envelope contains an acute three-tuple, so $\lambda(N)=O(N)$.

Comment: Do you mean the boundary of the convex hull? The 3x3 square does not contain an acute three-tuple.

Comment: Leave the enlargement-by-squares out for a moment and assume that for a set of points $S$, any triangle with vertices at three distinct points is obtuse. Consider the smallest (with respect to inclusion) convex subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$ containing $S$: let $K$ be such set (the convex envelope of $S$). If every element of $S$ lies on the boundary of $K$ to have only obtuse triangles is possible, otherwise it is not (not a sufficient condition, of course). In particular if we take $S$ as the set of lattice points in a square, $\lambda(N)=O(N)$ is trivial.

Comment: The $3\times 3$ square does not give a counter-example since $0\in O(N)$.

Comment: The difficulty is precisely the enlargement-by-squares, and that thin acute triangles are not stable. Do you see a way to get around it? I mentioned the 3x3 square because it does not equal the boundary of its convex hull, and does not contain an acute three-tuple.

Comment: The enlargement just makes the event "any triple is an obtuse triangle" less probable. If a set of "enlarged points" is free of acute triangles, the set $S$ is free of acute triangles too.

Comment: I think I see the confusion. An "acute three-tuple" is collection of three squares (s1,s2,s3) so that all choices of of points (y1,y2,y3) in s1 x s2 x s3 form an acute triangle. Thus, "the set of squares corresponding to S contains an acute three-tuple" implies that "S contains an acute triangle," but the converse does not hold. I have edited the statement to make this clearer.